# Differentiate between two set of points

Tags: clustering, dataset, k-means, algorithms

Consider two sets of points (in the pictures below), whose **"`center of gravity`" is same**. What measure can differentiate between the two sets?

*e.g.*

Image 1 and 2 has both `16` points, whose average comes to the same point for both the sets. I wanted to know what measure can be used to differentiate between the both. **How can I say points in image 2 are more cohesive compared to the other.** *(not sure if "cohesive" is the correct term for this, but I hope you get the idea)*

I **dont** want to use `k-means` because it will too expensive to calculate the clusters for every sets, and I have around millions of them.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried computing the [moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Notable_moments) of these two distributions of points? The "center of gravity" is also called the "first moment". Try computing the second and third moments and see how different they are.

Comment: Because these plots exhibit many different kinds of properties, it's unclear what you mean by "cohesive."  Would this be "smaller spread," "greater clumpiness," or what?  Once you can tell us your meaning I'm sure we can propose many ways of measuring it.

Comment: @whuber as you see in the second image points are more community oriented compared to image 1 where they are independent. I don't know the exact term - I thought cohesiveness maybe describes it. But you get the point I guess :)

Comment: I believe I do, but @Stef's comment reflects a different interpretation of "cohesive" as being the amount and directionality of the spread.  That's why it will be helpful for you to include some clarifying edits in your post.

Comment: @whuber  As I told, I really dont know what an exact term would be for this. But I am guessing there should be some term (atleast in Mathematics) to describe this. If you know, please let me know and I will be happy to edit this post.

Comment: There are *many,* depending on what specific aspects of the distribution you want to describe.  That's why it would be best for you to describe those aspects rather than making us guess what you intend.

Comment: Another property that is very different in the second set and can be measured as a number: calculate the average distance from a point to its closest neighbour. In the second set this average distance is going to be much smaller than in the first set.

Comment: If you want to compare the degree of "clusteredness" between the two datasets, search for methods to "assess cluster tendency" such as Hopkins statistic or VAT/iVAT visual block-diagonalization

Comment: If you have too many points, don't shun to take a random subsample.

Comment: What Stef mentions to do is related to the Hopkins statistic.

Comment: @ttnphns looks like this is exactly what I was looking for. Do you mind writing an answer to the question?